# Dojo chart add without changing axis scale

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, scaling

I am adding data to my chart like this:

```
electricStore.notify({ value: 0, id: ++electricCount, site: 1 });
electricStore.notify({ value: Math.random()*5, id: ++electricCount, site: 2 });
electricStore.notify({ value: Math.random()*5, id: ++electricCount, site: 3 });
```

But every time I do this the scale of the x axis changes so and an extra column is then visible.

How can I make it so that when I add a new column like this, a column off the other end is hidden and the axis scaling does not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update data yourself like in http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_chart2d_updating.html

Alternatively you can update data using the same ids like in http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_DataSeries.html or in http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_StoreSeries.html

Comment: Can I ask you also, how I can update the labels for the axis, I am using days of the week but I cannot find a function to update an axis. I guessed `updateAxis()` but that did nothing. 

Maybe I should also mention that when I removed the axis labels, so that numbers were displayed instead, updating my chart (like the first example) moved the columns but the numbers on the axis didn't change.

Comment: You can look up how to do custom labels in http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_labels2d.html and http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_label_shortening.html and http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_rotatedLabels.html and http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_chart2d.html (see chart #3).

Comment: That's great stuff - how do you find all these?

Comment: They come with dojox.charting. Just spend 10 minutes to see what is in the "tests" directory.